# Need to add primary and foreign keys to a column postgresql 9.3.2 using phpPgAdmin

Tags: django, database, postgresql

My apologies if this is a question with an obvious answer- but I am recovering from the lingering effects of a car accident, and still working to regain some of the things I used to know.

I've got a django application that uses a PostgreSQL database indexed by Xapian, and while I was in recovery, one of the columns in an empty table somehow got dropped.  When I returned to work, I found that running ./manage.py rebuild_index failed because it was expecting the missing column and couldn't find it.

To make the repair a little easier (I hope) I installed phpPgAdmin.  There's no problem connecting to the database, and I was able to add the missing column through the interface.  After that, the Xapian index was able to rebuild with no errors, but the table is still not functioning correctly.

I had hoped that the application would apply the primary and foreign keys once tested, but I am still seeing this in the phpPgAdmin interface:
[(Screen snip of the columns involved)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WxNc.png)

As shown in the link, the key icons in the top column are not replicated in the bottom column.  I'm fairly certain I can add them with ALTER TABLE, but if there is a way to do it in the context of the phpPgAdmin interface, I'd like to learn how to do it.  I just can't find any way to do it.

Any advice?